# Как в лямбда-функции использовать больше одной команды?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, lambda, exec

Как в лямбда-функции использовать больше одной команды?

Предположим у меня есть функция `f`, которая принимает аргументы. Я допустим присваиваю эту функцию как команду в кнопку tkinter:

```
b = Button(root, command = lambda: f('arg', 'arg2'))
```

А если я хочу параллельно добавить еще одну функцию как команду (не добавляя ее в функцию `f`?

Comment: можете уточнить вопрос и привести пример данных на входе и на выходе?

Comment: @MaxU Не понял, я имею ввиду в принципе:`lambda <some_args>:<some_commands>`...

Comment: трудно ответить на этот вопрос без примера входных данных и того, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: @MaxU Да я в курсе, я уже тут не совсем новичок. По-моему этот вопрос вполне нормальный.

Comment: @MaxU А return меня не волнует, главное просто исполнить код.

Comment: Злоупотребление: простые, но нетривиальные функции: Часто встречается использование лямбда-выражений для создания функции, которая возвращает несколько значений в кортеж python: `colors_by_length = sorted(colors, key=lambda c: (len(c), c.casefold()))`

Comment: по-моему, данный вопрос является [вопросом типа "Ошибка Молотка-Микроскопа"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Вы можете значительно улучшить ваш вопрос, прояснив изначальную проблему и приведя в вопросе пример входных и, особенно, выходных данных.

Comment: @MaxU Ну например так?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, [выбирайте )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865009/have-multiple-commands-when-button-is-pressed)

Comment: Не понятно зачем это вообще - сделайте отдельную функцию-обработчик и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Но если я Вас правильно понял, то так:

```
import math

def sum(x, y): return x + y

def mul(x, y): return x * y

x = lambda a, b: [sum(a, b), mul(a, b)]

result = x(1, 2)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного дополнительных определений и бойлерплейта на каждую конструкцию:

```py
def for_each(*seq):
    ret_val = None
    for thunk in seq:
        ret_val = thunk() if callable(thunk) else thunk
    return ret_val

lmb = lambda x, y: for_each(
        lambda: print("Hi,", x), lambda: print("Lo 0_o,", y), x + y)

print(lmb(20, 22))
```

Можно дополнительно определить класс Thunk, чтобы не исполнять вообще все исполнимые аргументы, но в питоне, кажется, это будет еще дополнительный бойлерплейт.

Answer (score -1):

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        def cmd():
            f1('arg', 'arg2')
            f2('arg', 'arg2')
        b = Button(root, command=cmd)
```